# Displaying graph preview in Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, graph

I need to create a toolbox in python, which will be used for **making graphs.**

I need the **parallel preview window** during the graph creation. Half of the screen will be used for settings the parameters and the other half will be a preview that would change according to changes of parametres. Something like **Create graph wizard** in ArcGIS Desktop (picture below).

Does someone have python code to split the screen, or some advice, or web pages?

Picture - Create graph wizard

[image: click here]

Comment: Try the following link.
[4-way split screen in pygame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403675/how-to-create-a-4-way-split-screen-in-pygame)

Comment: This looks like a use case for ArcObjects rather than ArcPy

Comment: I agree with @PolyGeo. However, you could build a UI outside of the ArcGIS geoprocessing framework using PyQT/PySide and embed a matplotlib graph. Something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459811/how-to-embed-matplotib-in-pyqt-for-dummies. But that would probably be off-topic on GIS-SE.

Comment: @Luke I think your comment is sufficient to provide an answer, and I agree that a PyQT/PySide/matplotlib question is for [so] rather than here.  If an ArcObjects question spawns from this it would be on-topic here.  In any event, I think the answer is "ArcPy cannot do the difficult part of this", and in its current unanswered state this question risks being too broad.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a python toolbox.

You would need to do this in ArcObjects if you want to stay within the ArcGIS geoprocessing/addin framework. Alternatively you could develop a standalone UI using a graphics toolkit, such as PyQT/PySide and embed a matplotlib graph. Something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459811/how-to-embed-matplotib-in-pyqt-for-dummies

Comment: Thanks for all answers....I have written this question also to Stack Overflow, but they told me: "Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. This is a Q&A site where specific programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get specific answers." ....So, I will try the standalone UI and I will see....